# Share your conky tips / scripts / .conkyrc

Tags: monitoring, conky

I've just started tinkering with [conky](http://conky.sourceforge.net/), and I'm hoping the StackOverflow crowd can share some of the cool things they've done with this tool.

Scripts and .conkyrc files specifically geared towards developers would be especially good to see. Some good examples of developer-centric functions would be repository-monitors or heck, even something that monitors StackOverflow.

Screenshots of what the functionality actually looks like would be appreciated as well.

Comment: Just stumbled upon a post about a pritty neat conky extension called ConkyPress. It shows the statistics of your Wordpress blog in conky (screenshots are also provided): http://evilshit.wordpress.com/2013/04/20/conkypress-a-wordpress-stats-visualization-tool-for-your-desktop/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This link just came up on reddit today, has some very well-done conky layouts: http://www.linuxhaxor.net/2009/05/07/8-beautiful-conky-desktop-monitor-setup/

Answer (score 2):

I have an old AT modem that understands caller ID connected to my computer, so it keeps a log of incoming calls, and will match them to numbers in my address book. I have conky set to show the last few entries from the log.

(An incoming call also triggers a script that displays the call details on the screen using osd_cat, and pause the music player too.)

Other than that, just the usual weather forecast and system info summary.

Answer (score 1):

I've just written a bash/shell script that uses grep to get today's TV shows from a txt file. Here's the format of the txt file:

```
Monday:
Family Guy (2nd May)

Tuesday:
House
The Big Bang Theory (3rd May)

Wednesday:
The Bill
NCIS
NCIS LA (27th April)

Thursday:
South Park

Friday:
FlashForward

Saturday:

Sunday:
HIGNFY
Underbelly
```

Here is the shell script which was saved in ~/bin and made executable:

```
#!/bin/bash
MYDATE=$(date +%A)
grep -A10000 $MYDATE /path/to/to_watch/list.txt | grep -B10000 -m1 ^$
```

And here is the line to add to your .conkyrc file (below 'TEXT')

```
$color${execi 3600 tv_today}
```

I think the regex/grep stuff needs some work (it doesn't like crlf line breaks) but it works.

Hope this gives someone some ideas of cool stuff to do with Conky...

Edit 2010-05-02:

Thanks to user tiftik for this more elegant awk/regex replacement for the bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
awk '/^'`date +%A`':$/,/^$/ {if ($0~/[^:]$/) print $0}' /path/to/to_watch/list.txt
```